# How to register custom events for socketio in backbonejs using browserify (commonjs)

Tags: backbone.js, socket.io, browserify

I need to put the events in a declarative way for the following socketio events:

- socket on connect
- socket on disconnect
- socket on message

Currently i put outside of the module.exports. I am using npm, gulp and browserify for my backbone app

The following code is working fine. I just want the socketio events registered in a normal way which is declarative inside the module.exports

```
    var $ = require('jquery'),
        Backbone = require('backbone'),
        homeTemplate = require("../../templates/home/homeTemplate.hbs"),
        socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:8080');

        socket.on('connect', function(){
            $('#incomingChatMessages').append($('<li>Connected</li>')); 
        });

        socket.on('message', function(message) {
            $('#incomingChatMessages').append($('<li></li>').text(message));
        });

    Backbone.$ = $;

    module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $("#page"),

        initalize: function(){
        },

        render: function(){
          console.log("home view");
          $('.navbar-collapse li').removeClass('active');
          $('.navbar-collapse li a[href="#"]').parent().addClass('active');
          this.$el.html(homeTemplate);
        },

        events: {
            'keypress #outgoingChatMessage': 'processOutgoingMessage'
        },

        processOutgoingMessage: function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                socket.send($('#outgoingChatMessage').val());
                $('#incomingChatMessages').append($('<li></li>').text($('#outgoingChatMessage').val()));
                $('#outgoingChatMessage').val('');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Inside a view function, use `this.$()` instead of the global jQuery function `$()`. Also, cache your elements: `this.$incoming = this.$('#incomingChatMessages');` to avoid doing the search again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Because socketIO is not a backbone component. You may use generic
  backbone events or wrap the socket in a model.
- Here is one way to use Backbone global events to handle events in the
  backbone view

  ```
  var $ = require('jquery'),
      Backbone = require('backbone'),
      homeTemplate = require("../../templates/home/homeTemplate.hbs"),
      socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:8080');

      socket.on('connect', function(){
          Backbone.trigger("socket:connect");            
      });

      socket.on('message', function(message) {
          Backbone.trigger("socket:message");            
      });

  Backbone.$ = $;

  module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({

      el: $("#page"),

      initalize: function(){
          Backbone.on("socket:connect", this.connect, this);
          Backbone.on("socket:message", this.message, this);
      },

      render: function(){
        console.log("home view");
        $('.navbar-collapse li').removeClass('active');
        $('.navbar-collapse li a[href="#"]').parent().addClass('active');
        this.$el.html(homeTemplate);
      },

      events: {
          'keypress #outgoingChatMessage': 'processOutgoingMessage'
      },

      connect : function(event){
          $('#incomingChatMessages').append($('<li>Connected</li>')); 
      },

      message : function(event){
         $('#incomingChatMessages').append($('<li></li>').text(message)); 
      },

      processOutgoingMessage: function(e) {
          if(e.which == 13) {
              event.preventDefault();
              socket.send($('#outgoingChatMessage').val());
              $('#incomingChatMessages').append($('<li></li>').text($('#outgoingChatMessage').val()));
              $('#outgoingChatMessage').val('');
          }
      }
  });
  ```

EDIT:

- I was able to get this running to a certain extent. It is missing a
  proper socket connection, but otherwise works fine.
- Please feel free to work on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/randomfifaguy/84rykj2q/11/). Many thanks to @Louis
  for helping me [setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40638142/set-up-jsfiddle-with-requirejs-socketio-backbone/40638447#40638447) the fiddle

Comment: `this.listenTo(Backbone, 'socket:connect', this.connect)` would be better to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: i really dunno what is wrong, but both listento and Backbone.on i tried, both not being triggered by the socket event

Comment: Could you move the both socket.on events & socket =require(...) to the end of the code (after view) and try? Because I suspect you are emitting the events even before a listener is active