# Set up jsfiddle with requirejs, socketio, backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, socket.io, requirejs

I've spent more than half a day trying to set up a **requirejs, socket.io, backbonejs** fiddle so as to solve another SO question.

Here is what I tried. You may checkout my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/randomfifaguy/84rykj2q/10/)
I tried a couple ways without any luck.

1. I've loaded the scripts in the head like this.

```
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.2/require.js"></script>
    <script>
    requirejs.config({
   paths: {
     'socket.io': ['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.5.1/socket.io.js'],
     'jquery': ['https//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js'],
     'underscore': ['https//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js'],
     'backbone': ['https//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js']
   },
   shim: {
     'backbone': ['underscore']
   },
   waitSeconds: 3
 });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='page'>
      <div id='incomingChatMessages'>

      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

2. Here is how I tried to load the scripts in the js component otherwise

   ```
   requirejs.config({
    paths: {
    'socket.io': ['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.5.1/socket.io.js'],
    'jquery': ['https//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js'],
    'underscore': ['https//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js'],
    'backbone': ['https//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js']
    },
    shim: {
      'backbone': ['underscore']
    },
    waitSeconds: 3
    }); 

    var io = require('socket.io')
    var $, Backbone;
    require(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function(jq, us, bb) {
      $ = jq;
      Backbone = bb;
    });
    Backbone.$ = $;
   ```
3. here is a [link](https://jsfiddle.net/deepumohanp/73xVu/) by someone who is loading jquery using requirejs in a jsfiddle but that only addresses my problem partially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of errors.

1. You should not use the HTML window at all for this. You can put everything in the JS window.
2. You should not put `.js` extensions in paths.
3. There's no need to use fallbacks for the code you have the the values in `paths` should be strings rather than arrays.
4. You had typos in your URLs in `paths`.
5. This line `var io = require('socket.io')` **cannot** work. This is RequireJS, not CommonJS. Such a call *could* work inside a `define` call.
6. Backbone has not needed a `shim` for quite a while now. Your `shim` for it is useless.
7. You don't need to do `Backbone.$ = $`.
8. For historical reasons both jQuery and Backbone leak themselves into the global space. So you don't have to do this manually.

Here's the cleaned up JS:

```
requirejs.config({
   paths: {
     'socket.io': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.5.1/socket.io',
     'jquery': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min',
     'underscore': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min',
     'backbone': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min'
   },
   waitSeconds: 3
});


require(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'socket.io'], function(jq, us, bb, io) {
  console.log($, Backbone.$, Backbone);
});
```

Note how the `console.log` relies on `$` and `Backbone` being in the global space.

And a [fork](https://jsfiddle.net/q4ah0udq/) of your fiddle.